# How to quickly select Necronomicon Archer to use mana burn

Tags: dota-2

When I use necronomicon it summons two units, warrior and archer. How do I quickly switch to archer to use mana burn before my target gets out of range?

Using tab switch it can be slow (especially if I'm playing Chen or Beastmaster who have more summoned units) and clicking the archer is unreliable if everything is clustered.

How do professionals do it quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick would be: the first time you summon your warrior, select the archer and assign it to a control groups (e.g. `Ctrl+1`). The next time you summon them, the control group 1 should already have the archer in it, so you can just press `1` then do the mana burn.

Comment: Do the control groups persists between games / heroes? For example if I play Beastmaster and assign control group, will the next game have the same control group? And if I play other hero than Beastmaster, will it persist as well?

Comment: No, but it shouldn't take more than a few seconds to set it when you first use the necro book.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Bibz is right, as far as I know this is the method most high-skill players use to micro their units. The key is summoning the necro units ahead of time so you can bind their control groups, then when you actually need them in a fight, you don't need to bother with it. The only unfortunate part is that you have to do this again every match you buy Necrobook, but it's not a hard habit to form.

Comment: This trick also applies to Necromancer's Golem, Meepo's clones, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can set "Select All Other Units" to "2" for example and once you have popped the Necrobook you can just use q and cast it. (You might have to press TAB before if the Archer isn't the first unit)

[image]

If you are playing a hero that already has units (such as Nature's Prophet, Invoker or Beastmaster) you probably need to use Control Groups.